# How to take entries from ListPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, listpreference

i want to make different actions using if statement based on what the user chooses from the ListPreference..this is a test code to try to print what the user chooses in text field..my MainActivity & ListPref class

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText et;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
}
public void show (View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ListPref.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    SharedPreferences sh = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String sel = sh.getString("pref", "1");
    String file[]= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.settings_repeat_by_labels);
    int i = Integer.parseInt(sel);
    et.setText("you have selected" +i+ "which is" +file[i-1]);

}
```

this is ListPref class

public class ListPref extends PreferenceActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PreferenceManager pm = getPreferenceManager();
    pm.setSharedPreferencesName("pref");
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.listpref);
}
```

The code displays the default value "1" no matter what i choose

sorry for bad implementation of the code

Comment: Please tell why it would not. Why the same "pref" key on two different occasions. Pretty confusing.

Comment: yeah sorry it was stupid mistake i fixed it..thanks

Comment: `Please tell why it would not`. Why didnt you answer?

Comment: `no matter what i choose`? What can you choosr? And what did you?

Comment: `stupid mistake i fixed it.`. But not here. You could give better info.